# gmaps: how to add multiple destinations

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, gmaps.js

I'm using [gmaps](http://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/) with JQuery. I want to display the directions from point A to point B, and then to point C, in a map. I'm using this code, but it's not working:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var map;
    $(document).ready(function(){
        map = new GMaps({
            div: '#map',
            lat: -12.043333,
            lng: -77.028333
        });
        map.drawRoute({
            origin: [-12.044012922866312, -77.02470665341184],
            destination: [-12.090814532191756, -77.02271108990476],
            destination: [-12.044012922866312, -77.02470665341184],
            travelMode: 'driving',
            strokeColor: '#131540',
            strokeOpacity: 0.6,
            strokeWeight: 6
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object literal you're passing into the `map.drawRoute()` function has the `destination` property repeated twice. A JavaScript object can only have one property with the same name, so the second `destination` overwrites the first.

The [documentation for `.drawRoute()`](https://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/documentation.html#GMaps-drawRoute) indicates that you should use a `waypoints` array for intermediate waypoints. While I haven't tested it, I suspect that the code you want would look something like this:

```
        map.drawRoute({
            origin: [-12.044012922866312, -77.02470665341184],
            waypoints: [
                {
                    location: new google.maps.LatLng(
                        -12.090814532191756,
                        -77.02271108990476
                    ),
                    stopover: true
                }
            ],
            destination: [-12.044012922866312, -77.02470665341184],
            travelMode: 'driving',
            strokeColor: '#131540',
            strokeOpacity: 0.6,
            strokeWeight: 6
        });
```